# Shortest Program to Sort a List of numbers into Odd and Even Category

Tags: code-golf, sorting

In the New [Modern Times](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Times_%28film%29), when Charlie Chaplin encounters a computer, he is employed in the sorting Yard, as a validator to determine if the workers are correctly sorting the items. The Items in question are packets of marbles. Packets with Odd number of Marbles are stacked in the Red Basket and Packets with Even Number of Marbles are stacked in the Blue Basket.

Charlie Chaplin is supposed to [punch the program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card) that would validate if there is any anomaly in the sorting procedure. Mack Swain his immediate Boss, shares an algorithm which he needs to code.

**Algorithm**

```
L = List of Marble packets that's already sorted
L_ODD = List of packets with Odd Number of Marbles
L_EVEN = List of packets with Even Number of Marbles
Check_Digit = √(ΣL_ODD² + ΣL_EVEN²)
```

His Job is to determine the Check_Digit and match it with what ever value his Boss calculates.

Charlie Chaplin during his lunch hours, were able to sneak to Mack Swain's drawer and determine, that his drawer has a single card with punches on the first <strike>46</strike> 32 columns (which means Mack was able to write a program with only <strike>46</strike> 32 characters).

Charlie Chaplin would now need the help of all the code ninja's to write a program with as few lines as possible. He also announces a bonus of 50 points, if someone can come up with a program which is shorter than his Boss.

**Summary**

Given a list/array/vector of positive numbers (odd and even), you need to write a function, which would accept the `array(int [])/vector<int>/list` and calculate the root of the sum of the squares of the sums of odd and even numbers in the list.

The Size of the program is the size of the body of the function, i.e. excluding the size of the function signature.

**Example**

```
List = [20, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5, 15, 17, 20, 9]
Odd = [9, 5, 5, 5, 15, 17, 9]
Even = [20, 4, 20]
Check_Digit = √(ΣOdd² + ΣEven²) = 78.49203781276162
```

**Note**, the actual output might vary based on the implementation's floating point precision.

**Score**

<strike>Score is calculated as `Σ(Characters in your Program) - 46`.</strike>Score is calculated as `Σ(Characters in your Program) - 32`.
Apart from the regular upvoting from the community, the lowest negative score would receive an additional bonus of 50 points.

**Edit**

1. The offset that was used to calculate the Score has been changed from 46 to 32. Note, this would not affect the leader-board/ bounty eligibility or invalidate any solution.

**Verdict**

After a gruesome duel between the Ninjas, Mr. Chaplin received some wonderful answers. Unfortunately few of the answers tried to take undue advantage of the rule and was not very useful. He actually wanted a fair duel and answers where the logic was coded within the function signatures would eventually mean the function signature is an integral part of the solution. 
Finally, Ninja FireFly was the clear winner and awarded him the bonus he well deserves. 
**Leaderboard (updated every day)**

```
╒══════╤═════════════════╤══════════════╤═════════╤════════╤═══════╕
├ Rank │      Ninja      │   Dialect    │ Punches │ Scores │ Votes ┤
╞══════╪═════════════════╪══════════════╪═════════╪════════╪═══════╡
│  0   │     FireFly     │      J       │   17    │  -15   │   6   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  1   │     tmartin     │     Kona     │   22    │  -10   │   2   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  2   │ Sven Hohenstein │      R       │   24    │   -8   │   7   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  3   │    Ben Reich    │  GolfScript  │   30    │   -2   │   1   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  4   │    mollmerx     │      k       │   31    │   -1   │   0   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  5   │ David Carraher  │ Mathematica  │   31    │   -1   │   3   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  6   │     tmartin     │      Q       │   34    │   2    │   1   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  7   │     daniero     │      dc      │   35    │   3    │   1   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  8   │    psion5mx     │    Python    │   38    │   6    │   2   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  9   │       O-I       │     Ruby     │   39    │   7    │   5   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  10  │      gggg       │    Julia     │   40    │   8    │   1   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  11  │ FakeRainBrigand │  LiveScript  │   50    │   18   │   0   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  12  │    Sylwester    │    Perl5     │   50    │   18   │   2   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  13  │     daniero     │     Ruby     │   55    │   23   │   1   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  14  │    vasuakeel    │ Coffeescript │   57    │   25   │   1   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  15  │      dirkk      │    XQuery    │   63    │   31   │   0   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  16  │  crazedgremlin  │   Haskell    │   64    │   32   │   0   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  17  │   Uri Agassi    │     Ruby     │   66    │   34   │   1   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  18  │     Sumedh      │     JAVA     │   67    │   35   │   0   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  19  │      Danny      │  Javascript  │   67    │   35   │   0   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  20  │     deroby      │      c#      │   69    │   37   │   1   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  21  │  Adam Speight   │      VB      │   70    │   38   │   0   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  22  │    Andrakis     │    Erlang    │   82    │   50   │   0   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  23  │      Sp0T       │     PHP      │   85    │   53   │   0   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  24  │    brendanb     │   Clojure    │   87    │   55   │   0   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  25  │  Merin Nakarmi  │      C#      │   174   │  142   │   0   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  26  │    Boopathi     │     JAVA     │   517   │  485   │   0   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  27  │      Noyo       │     ES6      │    ?    │   ?    │   2   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  28  │     shiona      │   Haskell    │    ?    │   ?    │   0   │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  29  │      Vivek      │     int      │    ?    │   ?    │   0   │
└──────┴─────────────────┴──────────────┴─────────┴────────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Why does the lowest score need a bonus, they already won?

Comment: Moreover, the offset of 46 doesn't change anything regarding the order.

Comment: @gggg I think they mean they'll give the lowest scoring answer a +50 bounty.

Comment: @gggg: I will actually start a bounty as soon as I am allowed to. So that's what I meant by bonus.

Comment: @Howard: `the lowest negative score would receive an additional bonus of 50 points`. So in order to qualify for Bounty, there should be at least one answer which fairs better than 46 characters. It seems now that we already have few :-)

Comment: "Score is calculated as Σ(Characters in your Program) - 32 [...] an additional bonus of 50 points.". So it isn't `code-golf`, which, according to the tag, simply requires *the fewest **bytes** of source code* .

Comment: @res: If you closely observe, the lowest score, is suppose to have fewest bytes. So this still remains a code-golf.

Comment: Hm, looks like scores were never updated.. @Abhijit, did you see the entries with the score of -31? :]

Comment: @Noyo: I have added a verdict paragraph, which might answer your doubt as to why your answer was not selected as the winning solution.

Comment: Aw, rats. Here I thought the rules were there to be taken advantage of, and that cleverness would be rewarded here. ;] Still, fun question, and good job, everyone!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### J, <s>18</s> 17 chars - 32 = ⁻15

```
[:+/&.:*:2&|+//.]
```

(As a "function body"; has to be parenthesized or bound to a name.)

#### Explanation

I tried making an exploded view of what each piece does, like Tobia does in APL answers.

```
               +//. ]    NB. sum up partitions
           2&|           NB.   given by equality on (x mod 2)
        *:               NB. square,
   +/                    NB. sum,
     &.:                 NB. then revert the squaring (square-root)
                         NB. (f&.:g in general acts like g⁻¹(f(g(x))))
[:                       NB. (syntax to indicate composition of +/&.:*: and (2&| +//. ]))
```

`+/&.:*:` could be replaced with `|@j./` making use of O-I's [complex magnitude trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20420/3918) to save yet another two characters.

#### Example

```
   f =: [:+/&.:*:2&|+//.]
   f 20 9 4 5 5 5 15 17 20 9
78.492
```

Answer (score 9):

### ES6, <s>(48 - 32) = 16</s> (1 - 32) = -31

*Original version:*

```
f=l=>(e=o=0)+l.map(x=>x%2?e+=x:o+=x)&&Math.hypot(e,o)
```

Entire function definition is 53 characters, body only is 48.

**Updated version, taking full advantage of the problem definition and moving pretty much everything out of the body and into the signature:**

```
f=(l,e=0,o=0,g=x=>x%2?e+=x:o+=x,c=l.map(g)&&Math.hypot(e,o))=>c
```

New function definition is now 63 "punches" total, but function BODY is now just **ONE DAMN CHARACTER LONG.** Plus it no longer corrupts the global namespace! :D

Usage:

```
>>> f([20, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5, 15, 17, 20, 9])
78.49203781276161
```

Comment: ...and now I feel kinda dirty. :]

Comment: +1, I've deleted my ES6 solution since yours is way better :)

Comment: Haha, thanks. We'll see if the rules are changed once the OP sees this.. ;]

Comment: Well, it looks like the rules were indeed implicitly changed, even after an answer was accepted and the bounty awarded. Oh well! I still consider this to be the solution with the lowest score according to the rules of the challenge. :]

Comment: Actually reminds me of those c code-contests where people would do all kind of trickery in the preprocessor making a seemingly 'simple' function returning very complex stuff. The net result was off course that compiling took hours & hours (& hours) while the actual execution would return pi up to 100k numbers (or something like that) in a fraction of a second as the result was pretty much hard-coded into the binaries. Anyway, although I think we both know you were were cheating I'd say "well played sir" =P

Answer (score 7):

### R, (24 − 32) = −8

```
f=function(x)
    sum(by(x,x%%2,sum)^2)^.5
```

The function body consists of 24 characters.

Usage:

```
f(c(20, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5, 15, 17, 20, 9))
[1] 78.49204
```

Comment: Ergh!!! You have **exactly** the same solution as I just elaborated!! `sqrt(sum(by(x,x%%2,sum)^2))` I only have not optimized the sqrt.... damn :-) +1 :-) PS: it is interesting how `by` seems to be out at first because of the shitty output format but when you run `sum` over it it is fixed ;-)

Comment: @Tomas In this example, `by` returns a one-dimensional array. One shouldn't judge the function by the result of the `print.by` function.

Comment: Nope, `by` doesn't return an array (btw, what you mean by "array"? There are none in R. You probably meant a vector), neither a vector. `by` returns object of class `by`.

Comment: @Tomas There *are* arrays in R. Have a look at [`?array`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/array.html). Furthermore, `is.array(by(1,1,I))` returns `TRUE`.

Answer (score 6):

#### Ruby 2.1+ — (39 characters total - 7 non-body - 32 offset = 0)

Slightly different approach. I create a complex number `a+b*i` such that `a` and `b` are the sums of the even and odd numbers in `list`, respectively. Then I just take the absolute value.

```
f=->l{l.reduce{|s,x|s+x*1i**(x%2)}.abs}
```

My previous solution, which is 5 characters longer but works on 1.9.3+:

```
f=->l{l.reduce{|s,x|s+x*?i.to_c**(x%2)}.abs}
```

On a final note, if Rails + Ruby 2.1+ were allowed, we can use `Array#sum` to get the body down to a mere 25 characters:

```
l.sum{|x|x+1i**(x%2)}.abs
```

Comment: Very clever, I like it! This would save me a few chars in J as well.

Comment: Thanks, @FireFly. Yours is nice. Gotta learn J sometime. Cheers!

Comment: You only have to count the body of the function, I'd say 37 chars.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @steenslag. Updated. I also shaved off an additional 5 characters by using the new Complex literal shorthand. Only works in Ruby 2.1 and above, though.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2.7: 45, nay: 40, nay: 38 - 32 = 6

Nothing very new here, just a combination of the complex number trick I saw in the recent Pythagoras challenge, lambda for compactness, and syntax/parenthesis minimisation:

```
lambda x:abs(sum(a*(1-a%2+a%2*1j)for a in x))
```

Update - saved a few chars. Thanks to @DSM for the trick of raising the complex component to 0/1.

```
lambda x:abs(sum(a*1j**(a%2)for a in x))
```

Ok, reading the question and recognising the 'body of the function' count rule saves another 2 chars:

```
def f(x):
    return abs(sum(a*1j**(a%2)for a in x))
```

iPython testing:

```
In [650]: x = [20, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5, 15, 17, 20, 9]

In [651]: print (lambda l:abs(sum(a*(1-a%2+a%2*1j)for a in l)))(x)
78.4920378128

...

In [31]: def f(x):
   ....:     return abs(sum(a*1j**(a%2)for a in x))
   ....:

In [32]: f(x)
Out[32]: 78.49203781276162
```

Comment: nice! it's like the problem was build exactly for `abs` of complex numbers

Answer (score 4):

### APL (27 - 46 = -19)

```
{.5*⍨+/2*⍨+⌿⍵×[1]z,⍪~z←2|⍵}
```

e.g.:

```
      {.5*⍨+/2*⍨+⌿⍵×[1]z,⍪~z←2|⍵} 20 9 4 5 5 5 15 17 20 9
78.49203781
```

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica 31-32 = -1

```
√Tr[(Tr/@GatherBy[#,OddQ])²]//N &
```

`GatherBy[#,OddQ]` produces the even-packet, odd-packet lists.

The inner `Tr`finds the totals, both of which are squared and then summed (by the outer `Tr`).

`N` converts from an irrational number (the square root of an integer) to a decimal approximation.

### Example

```
√Tr[(Tr/@GatherBy[#,OddQ])²]//N &[{9, 5, 5, 5, 15, 17, 9, 20, 4, 20}]
```

> 78.492

---

If `f[n_]:=` is not included in the count, an additional character can be saved.

```
    f[n_]:=
    √Tr[(Tr/@GatherBy[n,OddQ])²]//N
```

Example

```
f[{9, 5, 5, 5, 15, 17, 9, 20, 4, 20}]
```

> 78.492

Answer (score 3):

## Perl5 : (50 - 32 = 18)

```
map{$0[$_&1]+=$_}@ARGV;print sqrt$0[0]**2+$0[1]**2
```

Comment: +1 perhaps you may save a few chars by using `say` instead of `print` and `<>` instead of `@ARGV` (while supplying the args on the STDIN instead of on the command-line)

Comment: @Tomas Wouldn't using `say` require a `use`? switching from an argument array to `<>` would require an additional `split/ /,`.

Comment: 1) No, [say feature can be enabled from the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21502519/684229). 2) I guess no split would be needed if you provide those numbers each per line.

Answer (score 3):

## dc 3 (35 - 32)

Using arrays, as suggested by @Tomas. This saves some of characters because I can calculate the parity of each number and use it as an index, instead of tweaking the with parity as a method of branching and putting the right values in the right registers. Also it turns out that arrays will give you a 0 even if the array/index haven't been used, so you don't have to initialize anything.

```
[d2%dsP;S+lP:Sz0<L]dsLx0;S2^1;S2^+v
```

Assumes the numbers are already on the stack, and leaves the result as the only value left when it's done.

Test:

```
$ dc  
20 9 4 5 5 5 15 17 20 9  
[d2%dsP;S+lP:Sz0<L]dsLx0;S2^1;S2^+v 
p
78
```

## dc 16 (48 - 32)

First version using registers *o* and *e* to store odd and even numbers.

```
0dsose[dd2%rd1+2%*lo+so*le+sez0<x]dsxxle2^lo2^+v
```

Comment: +1 for using dc. Ha ha `sose` ;-) perhaps you could get shorter result using [dc array commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html#SEC10)?

Comment: @Tomas thanks a bunch! I first dismissed the idea of using arrays for some stupid reason, but after your suggestion I tried again and they turned out to be very helpful! A register had to be used to temporarily store the parity, but overall I think this is a much more elegant solution.

Comment: You are welcome, I knew this would help :-)

Answer (score 3):

## Kona, 22 - 32 = -10

```
{(+/(+/'x@=x!2)^2)^.5}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Prolog (73 - 32 = 41)

Here we count everything after ':-' as the function body.

```
f([],0,0,0).
f([H|T],O,E,X):-(1 is H mod 2,f(T,S,E,_),O is H+S,!;f(T,O,S,_),E is H+S),sqrt(O*O+E*E,X).
```

Call function like so:

```
f([20, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5, 15, 17, 20, 9],_,_,X).
```

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 40-46=-6

**Implementation**

```
function f(l)
    a=sum(l);b=sum(l[l%2 .==1]);hypot(a-b,b)
end
```

**Output**

```
julia> f([20, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5, 15, 17, 20, 9])
78.49203781276161
```

Answer (score 2):

**Python, 9 (55 - 46)**

```
lambda x:sum([sum([i*(d-i%2) for i in x])**2for d in(0,1)])**0.5
```

Using a lambda function saves some bytes on newlines, tabs and `return`.

Example:

```
x = [20, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5, 15, 17, 20, 9]
print (lambda x:sum([sum([i*(d-i%2) for i in x])**2for d in(0,1)])**0.5)(x)
78.4920378128
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 55 - 46 = 9

```
f=->a{h=[0,0];a.map{|v|h[v%2]+=v};e,o=h;(e*e+o*o)**0.5}
```

Test:

```
f[[20, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5, 15, 17, 20, 9]] => 78.49203781276162`
```

Comment: You can use an array for `h`:  `f=->a{h=[0,0];a.map{|v|h[v%2]+=v};e,o=h;(e*e+o*o)**0.5}`

Comment: @NeilSlater doh! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

## Q, 34 - 32 = 2

```
{sqrt sum{x*x}(+/')(.)x(=)x mod 2}
```

.

```
q){sqrt sum{x*x}(+/')(.)x(=)x mod 2} 20 9 4 5 5 5 15 17 20 9
78.492037812761623
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby (66 - 32 = 34)

```ruby
f=->a{o,e=a.partition(&:odd?).map{|x|x.reduce(:+)**2};(e+o)**0.5}
```

test:

```ruby
f.([20, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5, 15, 17, 20, 9])
=> 78.49203781276162
```

Comment: `Math.hypot *a.partition(&:odd?).map{|x|eval x*?+}` shaves off a few chars

Answer (score 2):

**Coffeescript, (57 - 32 =25)**

**Implementaion**

```
f=(a)->r=[0,0];r[e%2]+=e for e in a;[e,o]=r;(e*e+o*o)**.5
```

Comment: I don't know coffeescript, but i wonder if you can remove the space after the `+=` and change `0.5` to `.5`

Answer (score 2):

### GolfScript 30

```
.{2%},]{{+}*}/.@\-]{2?}/+2-1??
```

I don't think GolfScript has much of a chance on this one!

Answer (score 2):

### c#: 69-32=37

```
double t=l.Sum(),o=l.Sum(x=>x*(x%2)),e=t-o;return Math.Sqrt(o*o+e*e);
```

Full code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] list = { 20, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5, 15, 17, 20, 9 };
        Console.WriteLine(F(list));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static double F(int[] l)
    {
        double t = l.Sum(),  // total sum of all elements
               o = l.Sum(x => x * (x % 2)),  // total of odd elements, if even %2 will return zero
               e = t - o; // even = total - odd
        return Math.Sqrt(o * o + e * e);
    }        
}
```

PS: Just for fun, this works too, sadly it doesn't change the number of characters needed:

```
double t=l.Sum(),o=l.Sum(x=>x*(x%2));return Math.Sqrt(t*t-2*o*(t-o));
```

Answer (score 1):

**C# 174**

```
using System;class P{static void Main(){double[] L={20,9,4,5,5,5,15,17,20,9};double O=0,E=0;foreach(int i in L){if(i%2==0)E+=i;else O+=i;}Console.Write(Math.Sqrt(E*E+O*O));}}
```

Readable

```
using System;
class P
{
  static void Main()
  {
      double[] L = { 20, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5, 15, 17, 20, 9 };
      double O = 0, E = 0;
      foreach (int i in L)
      {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            E += i;
        else
            O += i;
      }
      Console.Write(Math.Sqrt(E * E + O * O));
   }
}
```

[image: Charlie's Output]

Comment: You haven't golfed this at all. We're trying to get a solution that fits on the boss's punchcard!

Comment: Why not? Explain Please.

Comment: Your code is fully indented with spaces all over. Code golf is all about getting the lowest character count. This question is tagged [tag:code-golf].

Comment: Thanks Riking. I edited it. I have fewer characters now.:)

Comment: I think the list is supposed to be provided as input, not hardcoded.

Comment: `Math.Sqrt(L.GroupBy(x=>x%2).Select(x=>x.Sum()).Select(x=>x*x).Sum());` You can Console.Write on the same line, and accept the input from args as a main parameter.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. But the Main method accepts only string as argument and we will have to convert it to double.

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab (44 - 46 = -2)

Function body is 44 characters:

```
C=mod(A,2)>0;O=(sum(A(C))^2+sum(A(~C))^2)^.5
```

Total function as follows:

```
function O = Q(A)
C=mod(A,2)>0;O=(sum(A(C))^2+sum(A(~C))^2)^.5
end
```

Tests of the function:

```
>> A = [20 9 4 5 5 5 15 17 20 9];
>> Q(A)

O =

   78.4920


ans =

   78.4920
```

---

```
>> B = [8 3 24 1 9 8 4 5 52];
>> Q(B)

O =

   97.6729


ans =

   97.6729
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2.7 - 64-46 = 18

This could be shorter using some `zip` magic, but for now:

```
(sum(s for s in x if s%2)**2+sum(s for s in x if s%2==0)**2)**.5
```

For completion, it turns out you can do zip magic, but it costs you more (by a few characters), so the above stands, unless someone can improve either of these:

```
sum(map(lambda i:sum(i)**2,zip(*[[(0,i),(i,0)][i%2]for i in x])))**.5
```

Comment: You don't need the [square brackets] inside the sum().

Comment: I think you could improve this significantly by working in the complex plane, e.g. `abs(sum(1j**(i%2)*i for i in x))`.

Comment: @DSM That is insane! I never thought of that. I can't edit that in its too much changed, but please make and answer so I can upvote it!

Comment: @DSM: I had a similar version in my mind, but yours is sleeker

Comment: Does Python accept `!s%2`?  That's at least an incremental change you can accept

Comment: @Charles: no, not `!s%2`, but that's a good idea: `~s%2` should work here.

Answer (score 1):

#### Clojure = 87 - 46 = 41

```
(defn cd [v]
  (let [a apply ** #(* % %)]
    (Math/sqrt(a + (map #(** (a + (% 1)))(group-by even? v))))))
```

Hardly idiomatic, though.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 64C - 46 = 18

```
c x=sqrt$fromIntegral$s(f odd x)^2+s(f even x)^2
f=filter
s=sum
```

Not too difficult to read. Example run:

```
*Main> c [1..10]
39.05124837953327
```

Answer (score 1):

**PHP** 85-32=53

`$a=$b=0;foreach($x as $q){if(($q%2)==0)$a=$a+$q;else$b=$b+$q;}echo sqrt($a*$a+$b*$b);`

This is the best i'ld come up being a newbie. I'm sure there must be some shorter versions as well.

**EDIT:**

A reduced version of the code could be:

```
foreach($x as$q)($q%2)?$a=$a+$q:$b=$b+$q;echo sqrt($a*$a+$b*$b);
```

This version only has 64 (21 less than the original answer) chars.

Said so, 64-32=**32**

Comment: Did it independently, got 58 base: `foreach($l as$m)$m%2?$o+=$m:$e+=$m;echo sqrt($o*$o+$e*$e);`

Answer (score 1):

`int e=0,o=0;for(int i :n){if(i%2==0)e+=i;else o+=i;}System.out.println(Math.sqrt(e*e+o*o));`

### Actual method in java code

```
public static void checkDigit(int[] n)
{
    int e=0,o=0;for(int i :n){if(i%2==0)e+=i;else o+=i;}System.out.println(Math.sqrt(e*e+o*o));
}
```

> Test Class

```
public class Sint
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if(args == null || args.length == 0)
            args = "20 9 4 5 5 5 15 17 20 9".split(" ");
        int[] n = null;
        try
        {
            n = new int[args.length];
            for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++)
                n[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
            System.out.print("int array is: ");
            for(int dd : n) System.out.print(dd+", ");
            System.out.print("\n");
            checkDigit(n);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void checkDigit(int[] n)
    {
        int e=0,o=0;for(int i :n){if(i%2==0)e+=i;else o+=i;}System.out.println(Math.sqrt(e*e+o*o));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Erlang: 82C - 32 = 50

```
fun(L)->F={lists,sum},O=[X||X<-L,X rem 2>0],E=F(L--O),math:sqrt(F(O)*F(O)+E*E)end.
```

Erlang isn't great for this. Most shortcuts end up being more characters (tuples etc.)

The only real things of note:

- `{lists,sum}` is a function reference to `lists:sum` and can be called
- Even numbers are calculated by subtracting `--` (*list subtract*) the odd numbers list from the full list

Can call using:

```
fun(L)->F={lists,sum},O=[X||X<-L,X rem 2>0],E=F(L--O),math:sqrt(F(O)*F(O)+E*E)end([20,9,4,5,5,5,15,17,20,9]).
```

Output: `78.49203781276162`

Answer (score 1):

### VB.net (81c - 11c = 70) - 32 = 38

Via liberal usage of the term *Write a function*

```
Function(n)Math.Sqrt(n.Sum(Function(x)x Mod 2=0)^2+n.Sum(Function(x)x Mod 2=1)^2)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### XQuery, (63 - 32 = 31)

**Implementation**

```
declare default function namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math';
declare function local:f($s) {
  sqrt(pow(fn:sum($s[. mod 2=0]),2)+pow(fn:sum($s[. mod 2=1]),2))
};
```

**Output**

```
local:f((20, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5, 15, 17, 20, 9))
```

[BaseX](http://basex.org) was used as XQuery processor.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell

**57 - 32 = 25**

Straight optimization of crazedgremlins answer:

```
c x=sqrt$read$show$sum(odd%x)^2+sum(even%x)^2
(%)=filter
```

Optimizations:

- `read$show` is shorter than `fromIntegral` - *3 chars*
- `s=sum\n` and two `s`'s has total length of 8 chars, two `sum`'s is just 6 chars. - *2 chars*
- making filter into operator does away with need of whitespace - *2 chars*

I also tried adding more stuff to the operator, but it ended up being just as long:

```
c x=sqrt$read$show$odd%x+even%x
(%)=(((^2).sum).).filter
```

Answer (score 1):

### LiveScript 50 (or 1 if you're flexible)

The 1 character solution is `r` where the function signature is this:

```
fun = (a,o=(sum a.filter odd),e=(sum a.filter even),r=(e*e+o*o)**0.5) ->
```

But I think that's a technicality.

Actual answer:

```
o=sum a.filter odd
e=sum a.filter even
(e*e+o*o)^0.5
```

Comment: Is it *really* a technicality, though? ;] http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20396/8856

Answer (score 1):

## k (31-32 = -1)

```
sqrt{+/b*b:+/'(.)x@=(_a)=a:x%2}
```

Example run:

```
  sqrt{+/b*b:+/'(.)x@=(_a)=a:x%2} 20 9 4 5 5 5 15 17 20 9
78.492037812761623
```

Answer (score 1):

## C (68-32 = 36)

```
float f(int *a, int c)
{int s[2]={0};while(c--)s[a[c]%2]+=a[c];return sqrt(*s**s+s[1]*s[1]);}
```

In action:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float f(int *a, int c)
{int s[2]={0};while(c--)s[a[c]%2]+=a[c];return sqrt(*s**s+s[1]*s[1]);}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%f\n", f((int[]){20, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5, 15, 17, 20, 9}, 10));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## ised (10 characters - 32) = -22

ASCII:

```
@={@+E$1@+O$1}
```

UTF8:

```
@={ΣE$1ΣO$1}
```

The variable `$1` must contain the array. Example invocation from shell:

```
ised --l - '@={ΣE$1ΣO$1}' <<<"20, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5, 15, 17, 20, 9"
```

Example invocation in interactive mode:

```
ised> @1{20, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5, 15, 17, 20, 9}
20 9 4 5 5 5 15 17 20 9
ised> @={ΣE$1ΣO$1}
78.492
```

Explanation: operators `O` and `E` extract odd and even elements of the array. The operator `@+` or `Σ` sums the array. `@=` returns the length of the given vector.

If you want a function, it's even shorter. Saving a function:

```
ised> @2{: @={ΣExΣOx} :}
```

The function body is only 10 characters long. The rest is the function declaration (`{: :}`) and storage of the function handle into memory slot 2 (`@2`). Invocation

```
ised> $2::{20 9 4 5 5 5 15 17 20 9}
```

Link to software: http://ised.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 60 bytes (bonuses not included yet)

```
proc C L {lmap c $L {incr [expr $c%2] $c}
expr hypot($0,$1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WcFZwUehOic3sUAhWUEFyMzMSy5SiE6tKChSUElWNYoFkrVcYG5GZUF@iYaKgY6KoWbt/4LSkmKFaGeFaiMDBUsFEwVTMDQEInMFkFBt7H8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 43 - 32 = 11

```factor
[ [ odd? ] partition [ Σ sq ] bi@ + sqrt ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcwxCgIxEAXQPqf4vbCoKKIW2omNjVgtW8TsLAZjkk0mhYin8T5eKcZd5hf/v2I6qdiFfDkfT4cNHpJviNQnsoriMKtktXIt4U7BkhmtS1axdjbCB2J@@qAtYyvEC/Mp1lhgOdysZDXSW@QaNVzb7tDAy8D6/6HQ94PYF7vqPSalBkaTlTQGVf4B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes - 32 = score -22

```
ḟḂƇ,ḂƇ§²S½
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjvkPdzQda9cBk4eWH9oUfGjv////o40MdBQsdRRMdBRMYcgQhM11FMBSsQA)

Answer (score 0):

**JAVA: 67-32=35**

inside function(int[] a) :

```
int x=0,y=0;
for(int i:a)
{
if(i%2==0)
x+=i;
else y+=i;
}
Math.hypot(x,y);
```

Comment: C'mon guys atleast tell why you've down-voted the answer.
Its a working code.

Comment: I didn't downvote. But why `i*i`? I also get `1108.9891793881488` when I run your code with the sample input.

Comment: I thought we need to square them first,then add them.....ΣEven² is actually (ΣEven)², while I took it as Σ(Even²). but I should've checked with sample input earlier.
Thanks @Danny.

Comment: If you're trying to make the code small, you can skip the curly braces and keep everything on one line.

Answer (score 0):

**JAVA 517 bytes**

```
 public class Link 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            int[]a={20, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5, 15, 17, 20, 9};
            int []b=new int[10];
            int[]c=new int[10];
            int j=0,k=0,l=0,m=0;
            for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            {
                if(a[i]%2==0)
                {
                    b[j]=a[i];
                    j++;
                }
                else
                {
                    c[k]=a[i];
                    k++;
                }
            }
            for(int i=0;i<j;i++)
            {
                l=l+b[i];
            }
            l=l*l;
            for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
            {
                m=m+c[i];
            }
            m=m*m;
            l=l+m;
            double t=Math.sqrt(l);
            System.out.print(t);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript 67-32=35

```
function r(a){k=j=0;a.map(function z(i){i%2?j+=i:k+=i});return Math.sqrt(k*k+j*j)}
```

Doesn't seem like there is an easy way of spliting the array into even's and odd's without defining another function :(

```
console.log(r([20, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5, 15, 17, 20, 9]));
78.49203781276162
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `ḋ`, 7 bytes - 32 = score -25

```
⁽∷ġṠ²∑√
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuIsiLCIiLCLigb3iiLfEoeG5oMKy4oiR4oiaIiwiIiwiWzIwLCA5LCA0LCA1LCA1LCA1LCAxNSwgMTcsIDIwLCA5XSJd)