# I'm walking around manhattan, how far am I from my hotel?

Tags: code-golf

**The unnecessary and convoluted story**

I am walking around [manhattan, block by block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) and my feet have gotten tired and want to go back home.

The traffic is pretty bad, but fortunately I'm very rich and I have a helicopter on standby at the hotel. But I need them to know how much fuel to pack for the flight and for that they need to know my direct distance from the hotel. I did remember which blocks I walked and can tell them what route I took. This distance needs to be precise though, if they are too short we won't make it back, too long and I've bought fuel I can't use.

Can you write me a program to convert that into the distance they will have to travel on their flight to fetch me?

**Specification:**

Write me a function that:

1. Accepts a list or string of blocks walked relative to an arbitrary grid:

   - **U** p, **D** own, **L** eft and **R** ight.
   - Can be either upper or lower case - eg. if its shorter to use `u` instead of `U` go ahead.
   - An invalid direction has undefined behaviour - eg. a direction of **X** can cause a failure.
2. Returns a float/decimal/double that is twice the straight line distance from the point of origin.

For illustration and clarification:

[image: My trip]

My trip could have just as easily been recorded as `"luluu..."` or `['l','u','l'...]` but it must be recorded as Up, Down, Left, Right.

Comment: You are enough rich to have an helicopter but you care if some extra fuel is bought? :O

Comment: @fezvrasta because I'm stingy.

Comment: Way to mess with my head by not making this about Manhattan distance.

Comment: The correct answer is "It doesn't matter. You're a rich guy, so you reach into your pocket, pull out a wad of $20's, and wave it in the air to attract the attention of a cabby; you are then set upon by a group of kindergarten thugs who rob you and beat you to a bloody pulp. You are then arrested for littering and public vagrancy, charged with terrorism for attempting to cause mass panic and a pandemic by spreading your bodily ooze across a public sidewalk, convicted, sent to prison, and locked up with a cellmate nicknamed Brutus who takes a *real* strong liking to you. Welcome to New York!"

Comment: Kendall says this isn't  about manhattan distance? "up" and "down" are not clear. Is this to mean that you made left hand turns, and this is as if you were on a map of manhattan, or are you just actually talking about manhattan distance?

Comment: @McKay I interpret it as directions on a map, anyway (otherwise it'd probably be "forward" and "back"), and the distance measure is rather unambiguous "twice the straight line distance from the point of origin", so no manhattan distance).

Comment: @FireFly but he's traveling in manhattan distance? And he's not making turns. the question doesn't say how we're supposed to interpret the directions. He could be making left and right turns? and "Up" and "Down" could be on a map, but in Manhattan, "up" and down don't correspond to street directions, because the grid is off by what 30 degrees from north? Also, in Manhattan the blocks are not even. Sure he references taxicab geometry, which alleviates those two concerns, but still doesn't fix left and right as well as up and down.

Comment: Try using North, South, etc.

Comment: @McKay I've added an illustration to clarify this.

Comment: @FireFly My thought was that **I** am travelling via manhattan distance, by my helicopter isn't.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr aha. Call me stupid, but... how do you get ~3.64 for the flight distance? :D  By my calculations the total travel distance should be 2 × (3 × √2) ≈ 8.49 (twice the distance between the coordinates).

Comment: @FireFly Cause I'm a moron who is bad at math and doesn't double check things :/

Comment: Good thing you're walking. One-way streets make it a lot more interesting. And good thing it's a "modern" grid city; even natives have been known to get lost in Boston.

Comment: Am i missing something ? because assuming the co-ordinates as (3,4) and (6,7) the distance is square root of square(6-3) + square(7-4) ~= 4.24

Comment: @Shiva the helicopter has to fly out to get me and then take me back to the hotel.

Comment: I don't like your map. The little flashy grey dots hurt my head. :P

Comment: @JamesWebster You jerk. I didn't see them until you pointed them out.

Answer (score 34):

#### J, 17 characters

```
2*|+/0j1^'urdl'i.
```

Uses the fact, that the powers of `j` represent the proper directions.

- `'urdl'i.` take string and calculate indices (0 for 'u', 1 for 'r', ...)
- `0j1^` transforms into the direction in the complex plane using the corresponding power of `j`.
- `+/` sums up the single steps
- `2*|` two times the modulus

Example:

```
> 2*|+/0j1^'urdl'i.'uuuudrrrl'
7.2111
```

Comment: Nice job. Maths knowledge for the win. :-)

Comment: Make this "non-extended" ASCII and then it's just 15 bytes (because you don't use the eighth bit).

Answer (score 14):

### Python 2.7 <strike>56</strike> <strike>58</strike> <strike>56</strike> <strike>51</strike> 48

With the stolen [Number One Dime](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Number_One_Dime) from [Scrooge McDuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrooge_McDuck), I made my fortune and now have more wealth than Scrooge.

```
y=lambda s:2*abs(sum(1j**(ord(i)%15)for i in s))
```

### Python 2.7 - <strike>61</strike> <strike>53</strike> 50 (case insensitive)

```
y=lambda s:2*abs(sum(1j**(ord(i)%16%9)for i in s))
```

**Implementation**

```
>>> from random import sample
>>> y=lambda s:2*abs(sum((-1j)**(ord(i)%15)for i in s))
>>> path=sample('RLUD'*1000, 100)
>>> y(path)
20.0
>>> path=sample('RLUD'*1000, 100)
>>> y(path)
34.058772731852805
```

Comment: I am getting `IndexError: list index out of range`. What form should the input have?

Comment: @plannapus: I have added an implementation section

Comment: Ah and it was `%5` not `%8`. Ok it makes more sense now :)

Comment: [-1 (plus updated lambda conventions)](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfpmAb8z8nMTcpJVEhx8pIKzGpWKO4NFfDMEtLSyO/KEUjWVPfWDMtv0ghWSEzTyFHU/N/QVFmXolCmoa6T6hPaGgQEIQGuahr/gcA)

Answer (score 5):

### APL (29)

```
{|+/2 0j2×-⌿2 2⍴+/'URDL'∘.=⍵}
```

e.g.

```
     {|+/2 0j2×-⌿2 2⍴+/'URDL'∘.=⍵} 'UUUUDRRRL'
7.211102551
```

Explanation:

- `+/'URDL'∘.=⍵`: see how often the characters `URDL` occur in the argument
- `-⌿2 2⍴`: subtract the `U` value from the `D` value, and the `R` value from the `L` value
- `2 0j2×`: multiply the vertical value by `2` and the horizontal value by `2i`
- `+/`: sum
- `|`: magnitude

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby 1.9+ (67)

```
f=->s{2*(((g=s.method :count)[?U]-g[?D])**2+(g[?R]-g[?L])**2)**0.5}
```

Example

```
f["DRUULULLULL"] => 10.0
f["UUUUDRRRL"] => 7.211102550927978
```

Answer (score 4):

### perl6: 44 chars

```
2*abs [+] i <<**>>%(<U R D L>Z ^4){get.comb}
```

- `get.comb` gets one line of input and splits into characters
- `<U R L D>` is a list of words, chars in this case
- `(1,2,3) Z (4,5,6)` == `(1,2), (2,5), (3,6)`, so it zips 2 lists into each other, making a list of parcels that `%()` turns into a hash
- `<<**>>` does pairwise `**`, extending the shorter list to fit the longer. Shorter list happens to only be `i`
- `[+]` sums all elements of a list, `abs` takes the modulus for complex numbers

Yes, I removed all possible spaces.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica <s>92</s> 49

Calle deserves full credit for streamlining the code.

```
f@l_:=2 N@Norm[Tr[l/.{"r"→1,"l"→-1,"u"→I,"d"→-I}]]
```

**Example**

```
f[{"u", "u", "u", "u", "d", "r", "r", "r", "l"}]
```

> 7.2111

Comment: You're doing a lot of work that isn't required by the OP, `f@l_ := 2 N@Norm[Tr[l /. {"r" -> 1, "l" -> -1, "u" -> I, "d" -> -I}]]` will suffice.

Comment: I get `2 Norm[(2. + 2. I) + "U" + "X"]` as the output for your code.

Comment: Yes, but the OP says it's OK to fail with such input. That is how I and everyone else interpret it. I can't read these other languages, but you will see that they often hardcode for u, r, l and d.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: If you replace two remaining pairs of parentheses with `@`s you get another two characters less.

Comment: shrx, I don't understand. The code has no parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

### PHP, 67

```php
function f($a){foreach($a as$d)@$$d++;return 2*hypot($U-$D,$L-$R);}
```

Example:

```php
<?php
var_dump(f(array('U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'D', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'L')));

>float(7.211102550928)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, 45

```
f(l)=2*abs(sum([im^(c=='d'?3:c) for c in l]))
```

Stole the `i` to powers trick. Also all the characters except d have values that work as acceptable powers for `i`.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2.7 - 65

Nice and short one, this uses complex numbers to step through the plane:

```
x=lambda s:2*abs(sum([[1,-1,1j,-1j]['RLUD'.index(i)]for i in s]))
```

Props to DSM and Abhijit in other questions that showed me the use of `1j` to calculate this.

Comment: Can `1j` be written as `j`, `-1j` as `-j`? Also, does this handle upper and lower input, or only upper?

Comment: [Uncle Scrooze](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrooge_McDuck), I hate you. You should at least leave some money for your nephews.

Comment: @DavidCarraher: No you can't. It would be impossible to differentiate between the variable `j` and the imaginary unit `j`

Comment: Didn't you say it was supposed to output **twice** the distance? when trying with UUUUDRRRL i'm getting 3.606 with this function instead of 7.21.

Comment: @plannapus Yeah I have a bad habit of adding code then changing it without updating my answer :(

Comment: You can save 2 more characters, by multiplying the constants by `2` instead of multiplying the final result.

Answer (score 2):

#### R, <s>86</s> <s>74</s> 56 characters

Ok it's actually way shorter with imaginary numbers indeed:

```
2*Mod(sum(sapply(scan(,""),switch,u=1i,d=-1i,l=-1,r=1)))
```

Usage:

```
> 2*Mod(sum(sapply(scan(,""),switch,u=1i,d=-1i,l=-1,r=1)))
1: u u u u d r r r l
10: 
Read 9 items
[1] 7.211103
```

**Old solution at 74 characters with xy coords:**

```
2*sqrt(sum(rowSums(sapply(scan(,""),switch,u=0:1,d=0:-1,l=-1:0,r=1:0))^2))
```

Usage:

```
> 2*sqrt(sum(rowSums(sapply(scan(,""),switch,u=0:1,d=0:-1,l=-1:0,r=1:0))^2))
1: u u u u d r r r l
10: 
Read 9 items
[1] 7.211103
```

Takes input as stdin, need to be lower-case and space-separated. Use x-y coordinates starting from (0,0).

Answer (score 2):

## k (<s>50</s> 49)

```
{2*sqrt x$x:0 0f+/("udlr"!(1 0;-1 0;0 -1;0 1))@x}
```

Example

```
{2*sqrt x$x:0 0f+/("udlr"!(1 0;-1 0;0 -1;0 1))@x}"uuuudrrrl"
7.211103
```

Answer (score 2):

### Java, 185, <strike>203</strike>, <strike>204</strike>, <strike>217</strike>, <strike>226</strike>

```
class A{public static void main(String[] a){int x=0,y=0;for(int i=0;i<a[0].length();i++) switch(a[0].charAt(i)){case'U':y++;break;case'D':y--;break;case'L':x++;break;case'R':x--;}System.out.print(Math.hypot(x,y)*2);}}
```

I did assume that each "U" was "1 up", so two units up would be "UU"

Edit: swapped out switch for ifs

```
class A{public static void main(String[]a){int x=0,y=0;for(int i=0;i<a[0].length();i++){int c=a[0].charAt(i);if(c=='U')y++;if(c=='D')y--;if(c=='L')x++;if(c=='R')x--;}System.out.print(Math.hypot(x,y)*2);}}
```

Moved for iterator

```
class A{public static void main(String[]a){int x=0,y=0;for(int i=0;i<a[0].length();){int c=a[0].charAt(i++);if(c=='U')y++;if(c=='D')y--;if(c=='L')x++;if(c=='R')x--;}System.out.print(Math.hypot(x,y)*2);}}
```

No longer takes input as string, rather array of directions

```
class A{public static void main(String[]a){int x=0,y=0;for(String s:a){char c=s.charAt(0);if(c=='U')y++;if(c=='D')y--;if(c=='L')x++;if(c=='R')x--;}System.out.print(Math.hypot(x,y)*2);}}
```

Comment: My understanding of the brief was that you only need a function, not a whole program.

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, 158

```
IF PATINDEX('%[^UDLR]%', @s)=0 select 2*sqrt(power(LEN(REPLACE(@s,'U',''))-LEN(REPLACE(@s,'D','')),2)+power(LEN(REPLACE(@s,'L',''))-LEN(REPLACE(@s,'R','')),2))
```

The @s is the input string of varchar(max) type

Answer (score 2):

### ES6, <s>77</s> 69

Definition:

```
f=s=>{u=d=l=r=0;for(c of s)eval(c+'++');return 2*Math.hypot(u-d,l-r)}
```

Usage:

```
>>> f('uuuudrrrl')
7.211102550927979
>>> f( 'uuuudrrrl'.split('') )
7.211102550927979
```

- Accepts string OR array (lowercase)
- Doesn't use imaginary numbers
- *Would not have been possible just 3 days before OP posted the question*; that is, it only runs in Firefox 27+ (and maybe also Chrome with experimental stuff enabled, haven't tested :)!!

(Inspired partially by Boann's answer.)

Comment: I really wanna do something tricky to get rid of the return, like turn the whole thing into a boolean expression that just gets evaluated and returned automagically, but I'm not sure there's a way to do this unless I can replace the `for` statement with some expression (an arrow function body containing statements require the brackets and the explicit return, bodies that are just expressions don't)..

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript - 142 characters - no eval()

```
function r(a){return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a.match(/u/g).length-a.match(/d/g).length,2)+Math.pow(a.match(/l/g).length-a.match(/r/g).length,2))*2}
```

where a is a string like 'uudrrl'

use like this -

```
a='uudrrl'
r(a)
```

Test in browser console.

```
var x = "luluurrrrurd"
r(x)
8.48528137423857
```

Answer (score 2):

## C# - 90 characters

Fresh from LINQPad.

```
int x=0,y=0;input.Max(i=>i==85?y++:i==82?x++:i==68?y--:x--);(Math.Sqrt(x*x+y*y)*2).Dump();
```

Where input is a valid string.

```
>string input = "LULUURRRRURD";

>8.48528137423857
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
O:3 ı*SḤA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/fyljhyEat4Ic7ljj@///fJ9QnNDQICEKDXAA)

I fiddled around with other functions to see if I could get rid of the space by finding a different one-byte dyad that would take a two-digit number on the left rather than the right, but it turned out that `:` doesn't need two digits to produce the desired values.

```
O            Codepoints of the input
 :3          floor divided by 3.
    ı*       Raise sqrt(-1) to the power of each,
      S      sum,
       Ḥ     double,
        A    and take the absolute value.
```

Answer (score 1):

### J, 29 characters

```
+:+&.*:/-/_2[\#/.~/:~'ruld'i.
```

Only works with lower case directions and any characters other than `r`, `u`, `l`, and `d` will cause it to give a wrong answer.

Usage:

```
   +:+&.*:/-/_2[\#/.~/:~'ruld'i.'uuuudrrrl'
7.2111
```

**Explanation:**

`'ruld'i.'uuuudrrrl'` The dyadic form of `i.` finds the index of items from the right argument in the left argument. In this case:

```
   'ruld'i.'uuuudrrrl'
1 1 1 1 3 0 0 0 2
```

`/:~` sorts this list into ascending order:

```
   /:~'ruld'i.'uuuudrrrl'
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 3
```

`#/.~` counts the number of occurrences of each number:

```
   #/.~/:~'ruld'i.'uuuudrrrl'
3 4 1 1
```

`_2[\` chops it into 2 rows:

```
   _2[\#/.~/:~'ruld'i.'uuuudrrrl'
3 4
1 1
```

`-/` subtracts the bottom from the top

```
   -/_2[\#/.~/:~'ruld'i.'uuuudrrrl'
2 3
```

`+&.*:` borrows [a trick from another J answer I saw this morning](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20163/737), and squares the items, then sums them, then  performs a square root. See [under `&.`](http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d631.htm) documentation:

```
   +&.*:/-/_2[\#/.~/:~'ruld'i.'uuuudrrrl'
3.60555
```

`+:` doubles the result:

```
   +:+&.*:/-/_2[\#/.~/:~'ruld'i.'uuuudrrrl'
7.2111
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Matlab, 51 characters

My Matlab submission, works only with captial letters. This was a fun one! The hardest part was converting the string into an array of complex numbers to be summed.

**Function:**

```
f=@(s)abs(sum(fix((s-76.5)/8.5)+((s-79)*i/3).^-99))
```

**Usage:**

```
>> f=@(s)abs(sum(fix((s-76.5)/8.5)+((s-79)*i/3).^-99))
>> f('UURDL')
ans =

     1
>>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 136

```
function z(a){var x=a.split('u').length-a.split('d').length;var y=a.split('r').length-a.split('l').length;return Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y)*2;};
```

Example:

```
document.write(z('uuuudrrrwl'));
7.211102550927978
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript, 89

```javascript
function f(a){U=D=L=R=0;for(d in a)eval(a[d]+'++');return 2*Math.sqrt((U-=D)*U+(L-=R)*L)}
```

Example:

```javascript
<script>
document.write(f(['U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'D', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'L']));
</script>

>7.211102550927978
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 120

```
float d(char *p){int v=0,h=0;while(*p){v+=*p=='U'?1:*p=='D'?-1:0,h+=*p=='R'?1:*p=='L'?-1:0,++p;}return 2*sqrt(v*v+h*h);}
```

`d("LULUURRRRURD")` -> `8.485281`

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (no ES6, no eval) - 131

```js
f=function(h){for(i=0,a=[0,,0,0,0];i<h.length;++i)++a[(h.charCodeAt(i)>>2)-25];x=a[0]-a[4];y=a[2]-a[3];return Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y)*2}
```

Test:

```
console.log(f('uuuudrrrl'));     // 7.211102550927978 
console.log(f('luluurrrrurd'));  // 8.48528137423857
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 44 bytes

```perl
$_=2*sqrt((y/R//-y/L//)**2+(y/U//-y/D//)**2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tZIq7iwqERDo1I/SF9ft1LfR19fU0vLSBsoEAoWcIEIaP7/7xPqExoaBAShQS7/8gtKMvPziv/rFgAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Befunge-93 (65)

It has 65 non-whitespace characters (217 with whitespace, though that can be reduced by a more compact layout (for 69/176 chars)). It takes some liberality with the output format, but is undeniably accurate. Doesn't seem worth the effort to implement/steal a square root implementation.

```
v                  >$:*\:*+88*4*5-2.,.@
               >3-:|
           >6-:|
       >8-:|
>~"D"-:|
       $   $   $   $
           \   \
       1   1   1   1
       -   -   +   +
           \   \
^      <   <   <   <
```

`echo 'UUDLLUU' | ./befungee.py ../man` outputs 2√13 (actually implementation seems to have issue with the extended ASCII though).